# window.plugins undefined in a service

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, toast

I have moved the function showToast from a controller to a service.
The goal is to share the showToast code across different controllers and directives.

```
var services = angular.module("myapp.services");

services.service('toast', function($cordovaToast){

  this.showToast = function(msg) {
    try {
      window.plugins.toast.showWithOptions(
                  {
                    message: msg,
                    duration: "long", // which is 2000 ms. "long" is 4000. Or specify the nr of ms yourself.
                    position: "bottom",
                  },
                  {},   // optional
                  {}    // optional
                );
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

});
```

After the refactoring, I get the following:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toast' of undefined
>       at Object.showToast (ToastService.js:7)
>       at ReportProblemModalController.js:77

Not sure how to expose `window.plugins` in a service.

---

*EDIT*

Not sure if this helps:

```
"cordova-plugin-x-toast"
{
      "variables": {
        "FABRIC_API_KEY": "xxx",
        "FABRIC_API_SECRET": "yyy"
      },
      "locator": "cordova-fabric-plugin",
      "id": "cordova-fabric-plugin"
    }
  ],
```

... however, I have the feeling the prob is elsewhere, as `window.plugin` is undefined in the service (and there are other plugins in the app).

Comment: What lib are you using for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify `window.plugins.toast` to `$cordovaToast`. `showWithOptions` is a method of `$cordovaToast`, not `window.plugins.toast` of course it is shown in the git repository . I think that is to be used in angular web app, may not in ionic.

```
  this.showToast = function(msg) {
    try {
      $cordovaToast.showWithOptions(
                  {
                    message: msg,
                    duration: "long", // which is 2000 ms. "long" is 4000. Or specify the nr of ms yourself.
                    position: "bottom",
                  },
                  {},   // optional
                  {}    // optional
                );
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

Comment: nice try, many thanks. but it is not working. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toast' of undefined`

Comment: In my code, there is no 'toast'. Please make sure that

Comment: The error because of `toast` property of undefined that is not in my code. May be your type mistake. just check for it